# Opendkim on AWS EC2 - multiple DNS replies for 'default._domainkey.X.com'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dkim

Hi I have problem with dkim key. My AWS EC2 instance is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

My Route53 DNS are:

```
X.com. MX  10 mx1.externalserver.com 
X.com. MX  20 mx2.externalserver.com
X.com. MX  30 mx3.externalserver.com

X.com. TXT  "v=spf1 mx ~all"

_dmarc.X.com. TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none"

default._domainkey.X.com. TXT "v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa; " "p=...KEY_STRING..."

...
```

NS, SOA and A records I belive are correct.

When I run

```
sudo opendkim-testkey -d X.com -s default -vvv
```

I get

> opendkim-testkey: using default configfile /etc/opendkim.conf
>
> opendkim-testkey: checking key 'default._domainkey.X.com'
>
> opendkim-testkey: multiple DNS replies for 'default._domainkey.X.com'

I haven't figured out solution, could anybody help me somehow? I will be thankful

I have alsot tried with different domain without MX records. I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread on serverfault which seems to discuss a similar issue you are having:

https://serverfault.com/questions/763815/route-53-doesnt-allow-adding-dkim-keys-because-length-is-too-long

Have you tried [DKIMValidator](https://dkimvalidator.com/) as mentioned in the thread above?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, your response was helpful. But te thread on serverfault relates to other issue that I have figured out yet.

I came up with another solution, edited my key files in /etc/openkey/keys/X.com/default.private and pasted there certificate generated by https://dkimcore.org/

Also was useful for me:
https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/dkim/dkim-check/
https://www.mail-tester.com/
and as you said DKIMValidator

I also had to change:

```
default._domainkey.X.com.
```

for

```
x._domainkey.X.com.
```

(its not domain name, just x).

Now my mails geting 9.8/10 in mail-tester :)
Thank you!